# bind9 multiple ports zone and dns64

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, bind

When I add the zone it stops working. How can I use them together? I want to go to the zone "." via port 5353
And go to DNS64 via port 53

```
zone "." {
type slave;
masters port 5353 { ::; };
file "/etc/bind/db.mk";
};
```

I want her to be like this example

```
options {
  directory "/var/cache/bind";
  forwarders {
    8.8.8.8;
  };
  dnssec-validation auto;
  auth-nxdomain no;
  listen-on-v6 port 53 { any; };
  listen-on-v6 port 5353 { any; };
  allow-query { any; };

dns64 2001:ff9b::/96 {
    clients { any; };
};
};
## new
zone "." {
type slave;
masters port 5353 { ::; };
file "/etc/bind/db.mk";
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want to configure BIND (Berkeley Internet Name Domain) to serve as both a DNS64 server and a slave DNS server listening on different ports. You can achieve this by defining separate `options` and `zone` sections for each configuration.

Here's how you can modify your BIND configuration to listen on port 53 for DNS64 and port 5353 for the slave zone:

```
options {
  directory "/var/cache/bind";
  forwarders {
    8.8.8.8;
  };
  dnssec-validation auto;
  auth-nxdomain no;
  allow-query { any; };
  listen-on-v6 port 53 { any; };
};

dns64 2001:ff9b::/96 {
  clients { any; };
};

# New section for the slave zone on port 5353
zone "example.com" {
  type slave;
  masters { your_master_IP port 5353; };
  file "/etc/bind/db.mk";
};
```

Replace `"example.com"` with the actual domain name of the slave zone, and `your_master_IP` with the IP address of the master DNS server from which you are transferring the zone data over port 5353.

With this configuration, BIND will listen on port 53 for DNS64 functionality and port 5353 for the slave zone, allowing both services to coexist. Just ensure that the rest of your BIND configuration, including the definitions for the DNS64 zone and other zones, is correctly set up to match your requirements.